# Extension to return parent type

Tags: c#-4.0, extension-methods

I know i can do this via Generics, as below, but how do i build an Extension to return the parent type with using Generics?

Generic Extension signature:

```
public static TEnum FromString<TEnum>(this Enum par , string val ) where TEnum : Enum {
    return (TEnum) Enum.Parse(par.GetType(), val);
}
```

Signature style, i know it wont work but kinda what im looking for.

```
public static this FromString(this Enum par , string val ) {
    return Enum.Parse(par.GetType(), val);
}
```

basically i have a series of Enum's that are having their values parsed to string for one process and as a receiver i need to parse that string value to the Enum for validation.  Ultimately if the `string` value is not a valid value in the Enumerator it will return a null, or `default`, value.  Its the fact i need to be able to return the `source` Enumerator's type without having to do a generic.

If its not possible, thats kewl, just figured i would try to do it without generics and do it with the extension logic pattern.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want this done with Generics?

Comment: already have it done as a generic, just wondering if its possible to do with extensions as a vice to generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you need the Generics to return the correct *type* of the Enum.
Otherwise, you'll just have the basic `Enum` type and not the specific type of your enum.

What you *can* do is create an extension method like this:

```
public static Enum FromString(this Enum par, string val)
{
    return (Enum) Enum.Parse(par.GetType(), val);    
}
```

But as you can see, you'll get a type of 'Enum' not of your specific enum.
On the other hand:

```
Enum val =  default(MyEnum).FromString("SomeEnumValue");
bool isEnum = val is MyEnum; // Returns True
```

As you can see `val` *is* of type `MyEnum` and isEnum returns `true`

This also works:

```
MyEnum val = (MyEnum)default(MyEnum).FromString("SomeEnumValue");
```

Comment: too bad i cant create a generic and then extend that generic within the Enum.  TY for the out of box examples.